# Restarting Apache causes huge spike in system load

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, operating-systems

I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy to a Tornado application and currently load testing websockets on the system.

Still in the prelim stages so the setup is as follows:

1. I built a Node.js script that establishes a websocket connection to the server. Once connection is established, it recursively establishes another.
2. I run this script up to 3000 connections from my local laptop while also running it on another server (different data centre than websocket server) up to 3000 connections as well. So by the time they both ramp up, hitting the server with 6000 connections.

I find that if I let it ramp up and then suddenly terminate each script (cancelling all 6000 connections) and then restart Apache, the system load of the server spikes like crazy. I'm talking like 300-500 (server has 16 cores).

But the crazy part is, nothing seems to be affected. The results of `vmstat` and `iostat` show that disk and CPU are mostly idle. My apps still run great. I even have a query to my Tornado application running in a while loop from my local machine.

Besides a small hiccup from the restart, it doesn't seem affected either. Any ideas where I can troubleshoot next?

Comment: Sorry but it's broad because I'm not sure where to go next. Yes, the script will establish a connection and leave it open before establishing another one and so on. Each connection also periodically sends a message (I have it set randomly). So by the time the script warms up, you have 3000 connections from one client to the server. I run this script from 2 locations for a total of 6000 connections.

Comment: If you need a reverse proxy then the best who can do it, it's `nginx`. It use conceptually different approach to compare with `apache` and can handle huge loading without taking a lot of resources.

Comment: Our application is a SaaS product where the users login in the morning and may or may not logout after work. We have thousands of customers. Since websockets stay active, 3000 is very reasonable as a staring point for us - we will likely need much more than this. I finished reading the articles. We did do quite a bit of work configuring the Apache settings but it may be worth rethinking them with the addition of the websockets. Thanks again!